# Filtrar array de números de acuerdo a diferentes rangos seleccionados

Tags: javascript

Deseo implementar un filtro de este estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde de acuerdo al checkbox seleccionado me filtre los valores de un array de números.

Por ejemplo con el siguiente array  `array = [180, 210, 250, 290, 350]` :

- Si solo tengo la primera condicion seleccionada (<100) el resultado
  seria un array vacio.
- Si selecciono la segunda condicion (entre 100 y
  200) y la cuarta condicion (>300) el resultado seria [180, 350]

Tengo la siguiente función planteada que podría manejar este tema, sin embargo siento que el código es demasiado largo y complicado.

**JS**

```
 function filtrarNumeros (array, c1, c2, c3, c4) {
 /*c1 al c4 son booleanos que representan si se selecciono la condición de filtro  */

    // f1 al f4 son los resultados de cada filtro
    // al final se concatenan
    let f1 = []
    let f2 = []
    let f3 = []
    let f4 = []
    if (c1) {
        f1 = array.filter(numero => {
        return numero < 100
        })
    }
    if (c2) {
        f2 = array.filter(numero => {
        return (numero >= 100 && numero < 200)
        })
    }
    if (c3) {
        f3 = array.filter(numero => {
        return (numero >= 200 && numero < 300)
        })
    }
    if (c4) {
        f4 = array.filter(numero => {
        return (numero >= 300)
        })
    }

    if ([c1, c2, c3, c4].every(e => e === false)) {
        return array // si no hay nada seleccionado devuelve el mismo array
    } else {
        return f1.concat(f2, f3, f4)
    }
}
```

Agradecería su ayuda para tener una versión mas elegante y legible que me permita resolver este problema.

Comment: si seleccionas opc 1 y opc 2, no se te repiten los números? por que varios array si luego los juntas en uno? por que no un solo array "result" y a este le vas enviando los filtros.

Comment: No se repiten, porque son rangos diferentes. La opción 1 son los números menores de 100 y la opción 2 son del número 100 hasta el 199. Yo utilizo varios arrays porque tengo entendido que si encadenó filter me va a trabajar con el resultado anterior, y necesitaría filtrar con el arrays base

Comment: Por ejemplo si selecciono que quiero los números menores que 100 y mayores a 300, y utilizó filter consecutivos al primer filtro solo obtendría los números menores que 100 y nunca encontraría los que son mayores a 300. Lo que se me ocurrió es que hago el filter al Array base por separado y luego los concateno, pero por eso pido ayuda porque siento que no es una buena solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para darle mayor dinamismo podrías establecer los valores mínimos y máximos en los inputs y basarte en estos para obtener los resultados. Fíjate que en el último utilizo la propiedad `Infinity` y luego convierto los valores de los dataset en números utilizando el unario `+` ([referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())), el cual también es válido para `Infinity`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const values = [180, 210, 250, 290, 350];
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    const result = [];
    targets.forEach(el => {
        const min = +el.dataset.min;
        const max = +el.dataset.max;
        if (el.checked) {
            values.some(v => {
                if (v >= min && v <= max) {
                    result.push(v);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

```css
label { display: block }
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" data-min="0" data-max="99"> &lt;100</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-min="100" data-max="199"> 100-199</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-min="200" data-max="300"> 200-300</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-min="301" data-max="Infinity"> &gt;300</label>

<button>filtrar</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jub90wtp/)

Comment: Excelente, me gusto mucho esta alternativa. Me estaba enfocando demasiado en usar filter.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
// arreglo de valores   
let val = [180, 210, 250, 290, 350];

// function entre valida el rango
function entre(min,max){
    // creamos un arreglo vacio que contendra nuestro respuesta
    let r=[];

    //recorremos en arreglo
    for (let i of val) {
        // si la poscion i del arreglo esta entre el minimo y el maximo lo agregamos al arreglo r
        if (i > min && i < max) r.push(i);
    }
    //retornamos valores
    return r;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

    // hacemos un recorrido de cada elemento input
    for(let x of document.querySelectorAll('input')){
        //validamos que este seleccionado
        if (x.checked){
            //extraemos su minimo y su maximo
           let min = x.getAttribute("data-min");
           let max = x.getAttribute("data-max");
           // lo enviamos a la funcion para entre para validar
           let r = entre(min,max)
           console.log(r);
      }
    }
});
```

```css
  label { display: block }
```

```html
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-min="0" data-max="99"> &lt;100</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-min="100" data-max="199"> 100-199</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-min="200" data-max="300"> 200-300</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-min="301" data-max="Infinity"> &gt;300</label>

    <button>filtrar</button>
```